# Send JSon from Server to Client in GCM

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I am Using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging).In that what i want i want to send J Son from the server side .On Client side I want to receive that for simple message i have done but i am stucked how could i pass J Son from the server side to the client side.

Please help me to resolve this.

This is my **Server side** code

```
 public class GCMBroadcast extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String SENDER_ID = "";
    private static final String ANDROID_DEVICE = "";
    private List<String> androidTargets = new ArrayList<String>();
    public GCMBroadcast() {

        super();
        androidTargets.add(ANDROID_DEVICE);

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String collapseKey = "";
        String userMessage = "";

        try {
            userMessage = request.getParameter("Message");
            collapseKey = request.getParameter("CollapseKey");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        Sender sender = new Sender(SENDER_ID);
        Message message = new Message.Builder()


        .collapseKey(collapseKey)
        .addData("message", userMessage)
        .build();

        try {

            MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, androidTargets, 1);
            System.out.println("Response: " + result.getResults().toString());
            if (result.getResults() != null) {

                int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
                if (canonicalRegId != 0) {
                    System.out.println("response " +canonicalRegId );
                }
            } else {
                int error = result.getFailure();
                System.out.println("Broadcast failure: " + error);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        request.setAttribute("CollapseKey", collapseKey);
        request.setAttribute("Message", userMessage);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("XX.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your payload (added to the `Message` by calls to `addData`) can only be name/value pairs. If you want to send a `JSON`, you can put a `JSON` string in the value of such name/value pair. Then you'll have to parse that `JSON` yourself in the client side.

For example :

`.addData("message","{\"some_json_key\":\"some_json_value\"}")`